# Refactor for using ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, proxy

I use VS 2008 and .NET 3.5

I have this code using CustomChannelFactory and Proxy ServiceReference. I would like refactor using lambdas, Action, ...

any suggestions ?

```
ServiceDependencias.IDependencias svcDependencias = null;

public void Dependencias(List<MfaFicheroForm> listaFicherosFormXML, string entorno)
{
    CustomChannelFactory<ServiceDependencias.IDependencias> customChannelFactory = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FicheroConfiguracionWCFService)
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(EndpointNameWCFService))
    {
        if (!File.Exists(FicheroConfiguracionWCFService)) 
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Fichero de configuración WCF no encontrado", FicheroConfiguracionWCFService);

        customChannelFactory = new CustomChannelFactory<ServiceDependencias.IDependencias>(EndpointNameWCFService, FicheroConfiguracionWCFService);

        var iDependencias = customChannelFactory.CreateChannel();          
        svcDependencias = iDependencias;
    }

    if (svcDependencias == null)
    {
        var depClient = new DependenciasClient();
        svcDependencias = depClient;
    }

    GenerarDependenciasDeFormulariosFmb(listaFicherosFormXML, entorno);

    if (svcDependencias is DependenciasClient)
    {
        ((DependenciasClient)svcDependencias).Close();
        return;
    }

    customChannelFactory.Close();
}
```

Comment: One of the reasons people normally program in english, is so more people can easily understand it ... e.g. like when doing a code review. ;p

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any Spanish so it was a bit difficult to understand exactly what was going on (I recommend you provide English translations/descriptions of non-English class names and string literals as comments next time).

- Why do you create a temporary variable that is only use to set another variable on the very next line instead of just setting it directly? (iDependencias & depClient).
- You close the channel if it's a DependenciasClient but don't clear the reference to it. svcDependencias is visible outside this method and having it hold a reference to a closed connection may be a problem.
- You don't check to see if svcDependencias is already set before setting it to a new connection. I don't know if you can re-use the connection, but you should at least close the existing connection before you loose the reference to it.
- I noticed that you only close the channel factory if the channel is not a DependanciasClient. While this will probably work ok if the channel factory never returns a DependanciasClient, I think a null check would be a clearer solution.

  ```
  if(customChanelFactory != null)
  {
      customChanelFactory.Close();
  }
  ```
- Instead of using the 'is' operator followed by a cast, you should use the 'as' operator and check for null.

  ```
  DependenciasClient client = svcDependencias as DependenciasClient;

  if (client != null)
  {
      client.Close();
  }
  ```
- If svcDependencias only exists at the class level for the benefit of GenerarDependenciasDeFormulariosFmb then personally I would prefer to pass it in as an argument rather then use a class field.